# Best way to add convenience methods to a Django Auth User model?

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication

I want to add a convenience/model method to the `django.contrib.auth.models.User` model.  What is the best practice for doing this since, last time I checked, extending the User model was considered bad practice.

I have a separate custom `UserProfile` model.  Should I be using that for all User-related convenience methods?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It depends what you are trying to add to the model. If you want to add more information about the user, then it is generally recommended that you use the `UserProfile` method: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users

However, if you just want to add custom methods or managers to the `User` model, I would say that it's more logical to use a proxy model, like so:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserMethods(User):
  def custom_method(self):
    pass
  class Meta:
    proxy=True
```

A proxy model will operate on the same database table as the original model, so is ideal for creating custom methods without physically extending the model. Just replace any references to `User` in your views to `UserMethods`. (And of course you can use this in the admin tool by unregistering the `User` model and registering your proxy model in its stead.)

Any instances of the original `User` model that are created will be instantly accessible via the `UserMethods` model, and vice-versa. More here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#proxy-models

(NB. Proxy models require Django 1.1 and above)

Comment: Good call!  Totally forgot about Proxy models.  I'm running 1.1 but was thinking in a 1.0 mindset.

Comment: Is there an easy way to change the type of request.user to the proxy type?  Is that necessary, or can I call the proxy methods directly on request.user?

Comment: I had the same doubt as @slacy and found a way on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11526049/188614. Basically, you have to subclass django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend, return UserMethods on get_user, and set it on AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS.

Comment: This link to Django documentation is now broken. Does anyone know the new URL?

Answer (score 14):

if you want to add custom methods to the User model, I would recommend [monkey_patching](http://www.alrond.com/en/2008/may/03/monkey-patching-in-django/):

create a file `monkey_patching.py` in any of your `apps`::

```
#app/monkey_patching.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User 

def get_user_name(self):
    if self.first_name or self.last_name:
        return self.first_name + " " + self.last_name
    return self.username

User.add_to_class("get_user_name",get_user_name)
```

and import it in app's `__init__.py` file. ie::

```
#app/__init__.py
import monkey_patching
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes. No need to mess with the foundations when your user model has a .get_profile() function attached to it.

Comment: +1, extending the User model is still not recommended, and all the plumbing for profiles is already there to utilise.

Comment: You can add a `OneToOne` field on the profile model and call `user_instance.profile` instead of using `get_profile()`.

Answer (score 3):

2013 update:

in 1.5 you can sustitute a custom User model and  add whatever you want https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#auth-custom-user

Answer (score -1):

I prefer to use the same UserProfile across various projects I develop and extend User for any project-specific needs. So, common functionality goes to UserProfile, and project-specific functionality goes to custom User. I have not had any adverse effects of having a subclassed User model yet, I wonder if there still exist any with Django 1.0+.