# Django: accessing one-to-one field in templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I have model `UserProfile` containing a `OneToOneField` on a class called `Info`:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, primary_key=True)
    info = models.OneToOneField(Info, null = True, blank= True)
```

in my template I have access to the profile with

```
{{user.get_profile}}
```

but **how to access `Info`**?
I have tried

```
{{user.get_profile.info.photo.url}}
```

without success.

Comment: Have you set the AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE setting?

Comment: @David Miller: yes, but it's a good remark

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676134/accessing-django-onetoonefield-in-templates

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't do that.

```
user.get_profile()
```

is a method and it gets executed when accessed as

```
{{user.get_profile}}
```

and not when you try to access more attributes of profile like `{{user.get_profile.attr1}}`

The way around is to send the profile object from the view. And if you want to have it in many view, you should make it a [TemplateContextProcessor](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#writing-your-own-context-processors).

There is also another way of extending the User model with an attribute profile that is a `@property` that does the same as `get_profile` which you can do as I have [described earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939941/django-user-model-adding-function/2943700#2943700).

Comment: A downvote for a right answer and no explanation? A first for me on Stackoverflow. :(