# Accessing Django OneToOneField in templates?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have the following scenario.

```
class A(models.Model):
    a = models.IntegerField()

class B(models.Model):
    c = models.OneToOneField(A)
    d = models.DecimalField()
```

In my templates, I have a list of objects A. In my template how do I access the attribute "d" from my template?

Thanks.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
class B(models.Model):
    c = models.OneToOneField(A, related_name='b')
    d = models.DecimalField()

{{ a.b.d }}
```