# Django - User proxy model from request

Tags: django, django-models

I use a proxy model on `User` like

```
class Nuser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
```

I use it throughout my views.
I was wondering the best way to get the instance of this object for the `request.user`

Each time I do

```
Nuser.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
```

Isn't there a simpler way to do it ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could write a custom authentication backend that returns instances of your proxy model instead of a `User` instance:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import ModelBackend

class ProxiedModelBackend(ModelBackend):
    def get_user(self, user_id):
        try:
            return Nuser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except Nuser.DoesNotExist:
            return None
```

In your `settings.py`

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['my_project.auth_backends.ProxiedModelBackend',]
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to have Django return, say, a `MyNurse` object whenever you query for `Nurse` objects. 
A queryset for `Nurse` objects will return those types of objects. The whole point of proxy objects is that code relying on the original `Nurse` will use those and your own code can use the extensions you included (that no other code is relying on anyway). It is not a way to replace the `Nurse` (or any other) model everywhere with something of your own creation.