# Different User proxy model per app in request object

Tags: django, django-authentication

## Current situation

- I have 3 apps in my Django project: `auth`, `polls` and `school`.
- `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in my settings is `auth.models.User`, and it is shared between all apps.
- the `login/` URL in `urls.py` is also shared between the 3 apps.

## What I need to do

I want to add some methods only to the users of the `school` app. To do this, I created a `school.models.User` model with `proxy = True` meta. This model inherits from `auth.models.User`.

## Problem

When a user logs in, `request.user` contains a "base" `auth.models.User` object, independently of which app the user is using.

How can I populate `request.user` with a different user model, depending on the app?

I tried using a custom Authentication Backend as suggested in [Django - User proxy model from request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682414/django-user-proxy-model-from-request), but I have no way to detect which app the user is using, so I can't seem to discriminate between `polls` and `school` in the authentication backend.

Comment: It's quite unusual what you're trying to do but what I would try to do is to resolve current URL to check app name and then based on app name return relevant model object. To do that, you would need an access to request object - thus you would need to write your own authentication middleware.

Comment: @marxin thank you :) Why is it unusual? What would be the usual way to do something similar? I think I might be doing something wrong with the structure of the project, but I don't know what the alternative could be.