# customizing request.user with a proxy model that extends Django User model

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

```
class MyUser(User):
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
    def do_something:
        ...
```

With the above, I extend the behavior of the Django User Model using the proxy model technique. I was hoping that I could somehow customize *request.user*, so that MyUser instance, instead of User instance, is assigned to it every time. How could I implement that, if possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can inherit a new middleware class from AuthMiddleware or create a separate middleware which will process request after django's auth and change request.user to your user instance.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'll look into Middleware. Cheers.

Answer (score 9):

I looked at code and my idea is here. Late but I think can be useful for others

**In file myapp/backends.py**

```
    from django.contrib.auth import backends
    from models import ProxyUser

    class ModelBackend(backends.ModelBackend):
        '''
        Extending to provide a proxy for user
        '''

        def get_user(self, user_id):
            try:
                user = ProxyUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
            except ProxyUser.DoesNotExist:
                return None
            return user if self.user_can_authenticate(user) else None
```

**And on settings.py**

```
    AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
        'myapp.backends.ModelBackend',
    )
```

Comment: Awesome, I've been looking everywhere for this. Any idea how to do something similar with the AnonymousUser model?